# UI Sortable then grabing last item it's allways go left

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Have problem with ui sortable js.

[image]

Then I grab content and with mouse go left top right bottom the content box go left alot. Then I grab 1st, second or 3 content box it's all good, they stay with mouse grab icon. Where could be the problem ?

HTML:

```
<div class="row row-7294174766 ui-sortable">
<div class="minmin-column col-sm-3">
    <div id="column-2787694957">
        <div class="minmin-handle-column">
            <div class="optionWrapper clearfix"><i class="removeColumn fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="addWidgets fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="showColumnOptions fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="dragibleColumn fa fa-arrows ui-sortable-handle" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        </div>
        <div class="columnBox clearfix">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque beatae quam fuga explicabo ducimus magnam aliquid necessitatibus possimus provident nihil qui nesciunt, odi.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="minmin-column col-sm-3">
    <div id="column-9177189472">
        <div class="minmin-handle-column">
            <div class="optionWrapper clearfix"><i class="removeColumn fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="addWidgets fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="showColumnOptions fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="dragibleColumn fa fa-arrows ui-sortable-handle" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        </div>
        <div class="columnBox clearfix">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque beatae quam fuga explicabo ducimus magnam aliquid necessitatibus possimus provident nihil qui nesciunt, odi.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="minmin-column col-sm-3">
    <div id="column-2343620337">
        <div class="minmin-handle-column">
            <div class="optionWrapper clearfix"><i class="removeColumn fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="addWidgets fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="showColumnOptions fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="dragibleColumn fa fa-arrows ui-sortable-handle" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        </div>
        <div class="columnBox clearfix">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque beatae quam fuga explicabo ducimus magnam aliquid necessitatibus possimus provident nihil qui nesciunt, odi.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="minmin-column col-sm-3" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
    <div id="column-9763480300">
        <div class="minmin-handle-column">
            <div class="optionWrapper clearfix"><i class="removeColumn fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="addWidgets fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="showColumnOptions fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="dragibleColumn fa fa-arrows ui-sortable-handle" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        </div>
        <div class="columnBox clearfix">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque beatae quam fuga explicabo ducimus magnam aliquid necessitatibus possimus provident nihil qui nesciunt, odi.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$( '.row' ).sortable({
   items: ".minmin-column",
   handle: '.dragibleColumn',
   cursor: 'grabbing',
   revert: 300,
   axis: 'x',
   placeholder: ''
});
```

LIVE DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/anonimnos/b2hk59sp/

Comment: Unable to replicate the issue as you described it: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/3ymuocLs/

Comment: @Twisty Maybe the problem is that sortable is in sortable. I insert all code: http://jsfiddle.net/anonimnos/b2hk59sp/

Comment: I added `$(function(){})` but I am still not able to replicate the issue in FireFox: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/b2hk59sp/1/ Will test in some other browsers.

Comment: Oh I just saw it! It is only happening when I grab the last item in the list, where the handle and the content seem to separate as you described. It's almost like some level of wrapping or something is being changed when the item is `out`

Comment: I just found a problem. Need to remove .row class . http://jsfiddle.net/anonimnos/b2hk59sp/6/ . Werd bootstrap .row class only has margin-right: -15px; margin-left: -15px;

Comment: Oh I see, that seems to have fixed it for you. Good catch.